# Google Cloud Platform - Pub/Sub push to private (VPN) on-premise listeners?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-vpc

Official documentation for Pub/Sub service states that Push is available to listeners that are available on public network:

> An HTTPS server with non-self-signed certificate accessible on the public web.

That sounds pretty clear - but I wonder if I haven't miss something. Is it in any way possible to have Pub/Sub service push messages to on-premise machines, that are not on public internet?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with [cloud Nat](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/using-nat)

- Reserve a static IP
- Link your DNS with this IP
- Create a subnet
- Create a route from this subnet to your VPN
- Create a Nat with your external IP and which forward request to your subnet
- Deploy an OnPrem webserver (apache, nginx) with valid certificate for your DNS
- Update your OnPrem route for reaching your webserver and don't forget to route the flow back!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it in any way possible to have Pub/Sub service push messages to
>   on-premise machines, that are not on public internet?

Not easily, if at all. You might be able to use a Reverse Proxy. This introduces several layers to manage: proxy configuration, proxy compute instance, SSL Certificates, VPC routing, on-prem router, etc. See guillaume blaquiere's answer.

On-prem resource can reach Pub/Sub via public Internet or via VPN to `private.googleapis.com` but Pub/Sub cannot connect to on-prem or VPC resources configured with private IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Pub/Sub push subscriptions require a publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint. If you want to reach on-premise machines, that would have to be done via a proxy/router accessible via the public internet (as others have mentioned). Cloud Pub/Sub does not currently support VPC for push subscriptions.

Please see the note section under https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are outdated. You can use [restricted Virtual IP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/restricted-vip-services) with [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) to provide a private network route for requests to Google Cloud services without exposing the requests to the internet.